# How to select parent using SCSS

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I would like to write something like this in SCSS:

```css
.username {
  color: red;

  @something .mobile {
    font-weight: bold
  }
  
  @something .desktop {
    font-weight: normal
  }
}
```

...to have the following output in CSS:

```css
.mobile .username {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold
}


.desktop .username {
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) `&` after the class, something like this:

```css
.username {
  color: red;

  .mobile & {
    font-weight: bold
  }
  
  .desktop & {
    font-weight: normal
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/651dbdd0b07d452c414b188354d673e5)

[image: SS]

**Note:** don't need to repeat the `color: red`