# How to choose the second parent when we have two parents in SCSS / SASS

Tags: css, sass

How to choose the second parent when we have two parents?

SCSS:

```
html {
    .ltr {
        direction: ltr;

        @at-root span#{&} {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
html .ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}

html span.ltr {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Output:

```
html .ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}

spanhtml .ltr {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Is the only solution to separate the two commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select parent using SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138710/how-to-select-parent-using-scss)

Comment: No, my code has two parents

Comment: @Mehdi didn't my answer help?

Comment: @mahan Your answer is correct and I will choose your answer if I do not get a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `span` out of `.ltr` and then use `&.ltr` inside `span`.

```
html {
    .ltr {
        direction: ltr;
    }

    span {
        /* You can add here more properties for span  that does not have .ltr */
        &.ltr {
          display: inline-block;
      }
    }
}
```

---

This also produce the same result. However, you can't use more properties on `span` that does not have `.ltr` .

```
html {
  .ltr {
    direction: ltr;
  }

  span.ltr {
      display: inline-block;
  }
}
```